A question about a multivariable limit
I have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,0)} \frac{xy^2 -y^2}{(x-1)^2+3y^4}$$ where the answer must be "the limit does not exist".
I set $y=m(x-1)$ and get $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{m^2(x-1)}{1+3m^4(x-1)^2}=0.$$ Converting to polar as $x-1 = r\cos{\theta}, y=r\sin{\theta}$ I end up with $$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r\cos \theta \sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta + 3r^2 \sin^4 \theta}$$ where if $\cos \theta \neq 0$ then I get $0$ as the result. If $\cos \theta = 0$ then I get $$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{0}{r} = 0.$$
What is the problem here?

Try a different path to $(1,0)$ and show that you get a different result. Then the limit cannot exist. For example, try $x=y^2+1$.

Does not it contains all the possible ways when $m\neq 0$ and close enough to the origin? And what is wrong with the polar coordinates?

The issue with polar coordinates is that you’re assuming $\theta$ is fixed here (i.e. the path is a line), but in order to keep the path arbitrary, $\theta$ needs to vary.

@kieransquared that is not the issue. The issue is fixing $y=m(x-1)$, that already restricts the path to a line.

@JulioPuerta OP used polar coordinates independently from fixing the path to a line. You can get the exact same result you did using polar coordinates by appropriately parametrizing the parabola. The OP reached the incorrect conclusion by sending r to zero with fixed $\theta$.

@kieransquared OP first fixed a line and then correctly used polar coordinates to find the limit through all lines is zero. This is a concept problem; thinking the limit is determined by all line limits.

Yes, that’s exactly what I said: the problem with OP’s approach using polar coordinates was that they assumed $\theta$ was fixed here, i.e., the path was a line.

Let's take a line passing through the limit point in parametric form:
\begin{align}
x &= 1 + l t, \\
y &= 0 + m t
\end{align}
and substitute into the function
$$
F(t) = \frac{l m^2 t}{l^2+3 m^4 t^2}
$$
to have
$$
\lim_{t\to0}F(t)=0.
$$
We can note that if there was not the $l^2$ term in the denominator, the limit would be infinite. But there is a problem, to remove the $l^2$ term we should set $l=0$ and the whole function becomes zero.
But we can avoid this by taking a finer approximation for $x$: look at $x = 1+lt$ as a first order Taylor expansion, then take a second order expansion $1+lt+kt^2$ and set $l=0$ to have $x = 1+kt^2$. With this position we get
$$
F(t) = \frac{k m^2}{k^2+3 m^4}
$$
and the limit is not zero, unless you take $k=0$ or $m=0$.
So we found a curve through $(1,0)$ on which the limit is not the same $0$ that we have for straight lines.
